# What do I need to get a node bootstrap site up and running?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, npm

My goal here is simple, be able to create my bootstrap based mockup designs and use some npm related tools that will compile my sass files etc.

I would also like it if I change a file in my IDE, it will reload the browser page for me.

I thought I needed nodemon but then I have to use nodejs/express, but I don't really need that just for design mockups.

What tools do I need to get this going?

Answer (score 1):

Unless I'm misunderstanding...

Perhaps what you're looking for is something like https://codepen.io, which will handle most, if not all of the things you're wanting.

If you want to use node features/packages/tools, then you need node. Nodemon is just what's commonly used to do change detection and trigger a page refresh in a node project.

If you want to use node as a standalone application setup, etc look at nw.js https://nwjs.io/